# How to insert data in the second row of a Gsheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gspread

I'm inserting data into a Google Spreadsheet with this code:

```
sheet_instance.insert_rows(my_data)
```

But it always inserts into the first row, where it has some important formulas.
Is it possible to keep the first row of the spreadsheet untouched and insert the data starting at the second row, with gspread library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`values_update`](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.values_update)

```
sheet_instance.values_update(
    'Sheet1!A2',
    params={
        'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'
    },
    body={
        'values': [[1, 2, 3]]
    }
)
```

---

[`append_rows`](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.append_rows) might be a good alternative too (you just need to specify `table_range`)